# setting database parameter in controller - codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have several country specific databases that all have the same connection properties except for the database name.

Rather than adding a database config for each country in database.php I would like to be able to set the database name parameter from the controller, then load the database config.

Something like:

```
$db->set_item('database', 'UK_database');
```

or

```
$config->sap->database = 'UK_database';
```

then do:

```
$sap = $this->load->database('sap', TRUE);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well first, I believe that you have some structural issues that may need to be taken care of first. For example, if they are country specific databases, why not just prefix them and place the tables in the same database?

Next, I believe you just want to be more dry. So in your `database.php` configuration, why not just replicate it?

```
$database = array(
    'user' => '',
    'pass' => '',
    ...
);

 $db['dbname1'] = $database;
 $db['database'] = 'Some other database';
 $db['dbname2'] = $database;
 $db['database'] = 'Another database';
```

At least you'll keep you're credentials dry and follow the CI convention of using multiple databases.

For example, if you need to update a record in one database.

```
$db = $this->load->database('some_selection_process', TRUE);
$db->do_some->db_related->stuff();
```